# create array with Foreach php

Tags: php

How can I create array like this using foreach

```
$data = array(
    (object)array(
        'oV' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    (object)array(
        'oV' => 'mysecondvalue',
        'oT' => 'mysecondtext',
    ),
);
```

Comment: RTLM? http://php.net/foreach. You're basically asking "I have a hammer. how can I build a house?". Learn carpentry first...

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @azizpunjani That converts an array to an object

Comment: @showdev That's silly, of course you can build arrays using a `foreach` loop

Comment: @Madbreaks Yes, you can. But `foreach` is not creating the array -- commands within the foreach loop build the array. I removed my comment because it was snarky, but my point was that the question is worded strangely or in an unclear/vague manner. That seems to be the general consensus.

Answer (score 8):

```
// Create the array
$data = [];

foreach($someList as $something)
{
    // Assign each value to the array as you cycle through the other collection.
    $data[] = $something;
}
```

**Something that springs to mind**

Foreach is used to cycle through collections. If you already have a collection with all of these items in them, then why would you want to re-assign it to an array?

Comment: well like i'm doing, to filter based on a condition within the foreach.